# Ruby - No gem to load in cronjob

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cron

I use rvm. and ruby 1.9.2 is installed in rvm.

I have a script and it runs fine in terminal. 
I have wrote a cron job for the same script:

```
27 * * * * su - sayuj -c 'cd /path/to/dir; /home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby script.rb >> /var/log/script.log 2>&1'
```

Then it shows no gem is to load error. I think the cron is not referring to the rvm ruby 1.9.2.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: put your script in a wrapper shell script that is called from the crontab. That will really help debugging and may just solve your problem. If it's does just clear up add a #!/bin/bash -x to the top and also take a look at the output of a call to env and compare to your command line results running env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `cd /path/to/dir;` to the real directory.
Then, create a file named `.rvmrc` with this content inside:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

It'll execute every time you enter the directory, setting to the correct version of ruby.